# Django views as_view()

Tags: django

```
Example views.py:
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')

Example urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import MyView

urlpatterns = [
    path('mine/', MyView.as_view(), name='my-view'),
]



classmethod as_view(**initkwargs)¶
```

What happens when a request from the user is received?
Is the view returned from ClassView.as_view() called?
Or is an instance of Class View created?

Comment: Yes, `.as_view()` returns a function.

Comment: So it returns a View function with some attributes attached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `urls.py` will call the callable that is passed to the `path(..)`. Here `.as_view()` will thus return a function that is called. You can find the source code for this in the [GitHub repositiory](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L48-L81):

> ```
> @classonlymethod
> def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
>     """Main entry point for a request-response process."""
>     for key in initkwargs:
>         if key in cls.http_method_names:
>             raise TypeError("You tried to pass in the %s method name as a "
>                             "keyword argument to %s(). Don't do that."
>                             % (key, cls.__name__))
>         if not hasattr(cls, key):
>             raise TypeError("%s() received an invalid keyword %r. as_view "
>                             "only accepts arguments that are already "
>                             "attributes of the class." % (cls.__name__, key))
>
>     def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
>         self = cls(**initkwargs)
>         if hasattr(self, 'get') and not hasattr(self, 'head'):
>             self.head = self.get
>         self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
>         if not hasattr(self, 'request'):
>             raise AttributeError(
>                 "%s instance has no 'request' attribute. Did you override "
>                 "setup() and forget to call super()?" % cls.__name__
>             )
>         return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     view.view_class = cls
>     view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs
>
>     # take name and docstring from class
>     update_wrapper(view, cls, updated=())
>
>     # and possible attributes set by decorators
>     # like csrf_exempt from dispatch
>     update_wrapper(view, cls.dispatch, assigned=())
>     return view
> ```

It will thus return the `view` function that it constructs in the `as_view()` method. When the `view()` method is then called when you "trigger" the view, it will construct a `View` instance with the optional `**initkwargs` you passed to the `as_view()` method. This thus means that each HTTP request, will construct a *new* `View` object.

Next it will "setup" the obect by adding the `request`, the `args` and the `kwargs` to the instance. Finally it will call `self.dispatch(..)` this method will take a look at the request method (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, …), look if it is part of the acceptable methods, and in that case trigger the corresponding `.get(..)`, `.post(..)`, `.put(..)`, … method, and return the result of that method.

Comment: is @classonlymethod Djangos own decorator for class methods?

Comment: @StreamlineAstra: yes, it is a subclass of `@classmethod`, and it will raise an exception if you incorrectly use it (as in calling `self.as_view()` for example): https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/decorators.py#L6

Comment: What is usually passed to as_view() for **initkwargs?

Comment: @StreamlineAstra: you can for example pass a `template_name` or other class attributes that you do not specify in the class-based view itself, for example if you want to use the view several times, each time with minor changes.